# What does "take subject to" mean?

Tags: phrases, legalese

Lord Browne-Wilkinson used this phrase twice in *Barclays Bank plc v O’Brien* [[1993] UKHL 6](https://www.bailii.org/uk/cases/UKHL/1993/6.html) (21 October 1993). 1.

> If the creditor bank has notice, actual or constructive, of the undue
>   influence exercised by the husband (and consequentially of the wife's
>   equity to set aside the transaction) the creditor will ***take subject to***
>   that equity and the wife can set aside the transaction against the
>   creditor (albeit a purchaser for value) as well as against the
>   husband.

2.

> Where a wife has agreed to stand surety for her husband's debts as a
>   result of undue influence or misrepresentation, the creditor will ***take
>   subject to*** the wife's equity to set aside the transaction if the
>   circumstances are such as to put the creditor on inquiry as to the
>   circumstances in which she agreed to stand surety.

Comment: The phrase isn't *take subject to*, it's *will take* followed by *subject to that equity*

Comment: put a comma after the word take and it will be a little more understandable.

Comment: _Take subject to_ is not a constituent; it's the last word of one constituent (_take_), followed by the first two words of the next constituent (_subject to_). Strings are not part of language; grammar is not a [_BBoW_](http://arnoldzwicky.wordpress.com/2011/11/07/bbow/)

Comment: Also note that this is legalese. It's not meant to be easily understood, but it *is* meant to be specific and precise as to how it will be parsed by courts of law. There are many, many sets of legal phrases and sentences that are used precisely because their meaning has already been argued and decided in court.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *take [subject to](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/subject+to)* (something) means *take possession of*, in this case, a wife's equity that is standing surety against her husband's debt. If the bank takes subject to the equity, they purchase it from the wife *subject to* any conditions previously put upon it – interest owed, mortgage payment, etc. However, the bank is not required to pay them; the wife is. If the bank doesn't pay them and the wife can't, the wife may foreclose or claim bankruptcy and the bank would lose the equity value.

Another option would be for the bank to *[assume](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/assume)* the wife's equity. In this case, the bank would not just buy the equity, they would also *assume* all appertaining responsibilities.

Comment: '[T]ake subject to' here isn't, as JL says above, a constituent and shouldn't be analysed as a whole just because OP bolds the three-word string. It's rather like analysing _take up_ in 'I will _take up_' when the sentence reads  '... the train I will _take up to_ London'. A comma between _take_ and _subject to_ is quite reasonable.